# What are the relevant pK values on HEPES?

Tags: acid-base, amino-acids, organosulfur-compounds

HEPES is 2-[4-(2-Hydroxyethyl)piperazin-1-yl]ethane-1-sulfonic acid. I have read (MA Al-Ghobashy, Bull of Faculty of Pharmacy, Cairo University 2014; 52: 71-78) that the sulfonic acid group is completely dissociated "over almost the whole pH range" and there are two basic nitrogens N1 and N2 stated to have pKa 3 and 7.5 in the mentioned paper and in [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEPES). But what is the pKa of the sulfonic acid group? And, in the opposite end we have an OH group - is this inert or does it ever give off the proton?

Comment: Both of these values are quite extreme, not really relevant in aq. solutions. Also they probably weren't investigated. Still these are probably typical values for sulfonic acids and alcohols. Did you search for what is usual for them?

Comment: @Sam202 No, it doesn't. These are pKa values for both nitrogens. To protonate sulfonic group, you'd need to first have them both protonated, and then go a lot further than that.

Comment: @Mithoron This [source](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/la5018938) claims otherwise.

Comment: @Sam202 It's pretty impressive they make such error even in paper! This paper isn't about this compound's acidity, though, so could happen. If there weren't *two* nitrogens, it would be true.

Comment: @Mithoron You're right. However, I'm finding conflicting information with respect to those pKa values belonging to the nitrogen atoms. According to this [source](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/hepes#section=2D-Structure) the pKa of HEPES is 7.55 (at 25°C), and its conjugate base referenced there is the deprotonated form of HEPES with respect to the sulfonic group.

Comment: Also, the two nitrogen atoms in HEPES don't have any hydrogen atoms bonded to them, so they should have pKaH values but not pKa values.

Comment: HEAP is a zwitterionic sulfonic acid, which should be in neutral form in aqueous solutions like amino acids. Therefore, pKa of 7.55 sounds correct.

Comment: @Sam202 Yes, these are both $p\mathrm{K_{BH^+}}$ values. Below pH=8 it's a simple anion. Between about 3-7 it's a zwitterion like a usual amino acid and at higher pH its second nitrogen is also protonated.

Comment: Sulfonic acid strength is typically estimated as 10^6 stronger than the respective carboxylic acid. R-OH aciity will be comparable to ethanol.